# ¿Por qué el género masculino suele dominar a la hora de referirse a colectivos?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género

Últimamente ha pasado por mis manos un documento hablando del tema del lenguaje sexista y, *long story short*, venía hablando de hacer referencia siempre a *doctores/doctoras*, *profesores/profesoras*, etc. cuando nos estuviéramos refiriendo a un colectivo.

Pensando un poco a qué venía esto de que el masculino dominara a la hora de referirse a colectivos, llegué a una conclusión basada en hechos históricos y que no pasa, necesariamente por el machismo:

> En años pasados, y durante mucho tiempo hasta hace no demasiado, no se solía encontrar a demasiadas mujeres fuera del hogar trabajando en un hospital o un colegio, por lo que lo normal era referirse al colectivo de, por ejemplo, *encargados de la salud* como *doctores*. Así mismo, cuando se habla del colectivo de *encargados de la limpieza*, se suele hacer referencia a él como *las de la limpieza* ya que ha sido mucho más común ver a mujeres limpiando que a hombres.

Pero esta es mi pequeña teoría, lo que me gustaría saber es si, de verdad, existe un motivo documentado por el que esto sea así.

Answer (score 3):

El género masculino suele dominar a la hora de referirse a colectivos porque el género femenino es el género excluyente (mientras que el masculino es el genérico).

De esta consulta a la RAE: [Los ciudadanos y las ciudadanas, los niños y las niñas](https://www.rae.es/consultas/los-ciudadanos-y-las-ciudadanas-los-ninos-y-las-ninas)<sup>1</sup> extraemos que:

- En los sustantivos que designan seres animados existe la posibilidad del **uso genérico del masculino para designar la clase**, es decir, a todos los individuos de la especie, sin distinción de sexos: *Todos los ciudadanos mayores de edad tienen derecho a voto*.
- El uso genérico del masculino se basa en su condición de **término no marcado** en la oposición masculino/femenino. Por ello, es incorrecto emplear el femenino para aludir conjuntamente a ambos sexos, con independencia del número de individuos de cada sexo que formen parte del conjunto. Así, los alumnos es la única forma correcta de referirse a un grupo mixto, aunque el número de alumnas sea superior al de alumnos varones.

En tu pregunta decías:

> Pensando un poco a qué venía esto de que el masculino dominara a la hora de referirse a colectivos, llegué a una conclusión **basada en hechos históricos** y que no pasa, necesariamente por el machismo

De esa respuesta de la RAE entendemos que no son necesariamente solo los "hechos históricos" (salvo que queramos entender como "históricos" la evolución propia del lenguaje, pero en realidad intervienen más factores en la manera en la que hablamos que el contexto social), lo que motiva que domine el masculino.

El femenino es el género marcado, es decir, el género exclusivo (solo se refiere a mujeres y excluye, por tanto, a cualquier varón). En referencia a la totalidad de los integrantes de un grupo mixto, lo normal y recomendable es emplear el masculino como género no marcado: *todos*. Incluso en latín se registra el mismo uso de masculino como género inclusivo y femenino como el exclusivo (filii = conjunto de hijos e hijas, reges = rey y reina)<sup>2</sup>.

Al hablar de ciertos colectivos solemos entender que han estado tradicionalmente formados exclusivamente por individuos de un sexo determinado (como las amas de casa). Supongo que ahí sí puedes decir que, por ciertos motivos histórico y socioculturales, entendemos que algunos colectivos están formados o han estado formados (casi) exclusivamente por féminas y el resto, (la gran mayoría) al ser exclusivamente masculinos o mixtos, se designan con género masculino.

Lo que quiero destacar es que no decimos necesariamente "los bomberos" porque el cuerpo de bomberos haya sido tradicionalmente exclusivamente masculino, sino porque el masculino es género neutro o inclusivo.

---

<sup>1</sup> Las respuestas proporcionadas para esa consulta se fundamentan en el punto dos (Uso del masculino en referencia a seres de ambos sexos) de [la entrada del diccionario de la RAE sobre género](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg))

- 2.1 En los sustantivos que designan seres animados, el masculino gramatical no solo se emplea para referirse a los individuos de sexo masculino, sino también para designar la clase, esto es, a todos los individuos de la especie, sin distinción de sexos [...] Así, con la expresión los alumnos **podemos referirnos a un colectivo formado exclusivamente por alumnos varones, pero también a un colectivo mixto**, formado por chicos y chicas. A pesar de ello, en los últimos tiempos, por razones de corrección política, **que no de corrección lingüística**, se está extendiendo la costumbre de hacer explícita en estos casos la alusión a ambos sexos [...] Se olvida que en la lengua está prevista la posibilidad de referirse a colectivos mixtos a través del género gramatical masculino, **posibilidad en la que no debe verse intención discriminatoria alguna, sino la aplicación de la ley lingüística de la economía expresiva**

<sup>2</sup> [Desdoblamientos y género no marcado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_no_sexista#Postura_de_la_Real_Academia_Espa%C3%B1ola)

> existen diversas teorías lingüísticas que afirman que **la forma masculina no predomina debido a la discriminación de la mujer, dado que en latín [que es de donde procede nuestra lengua], las terminaciones de los nombres, adjetivos y pronombres en acusativo singular suelen coincidir en sus formas masculina y neutra**, lo que habría hecho que los géneros masculino y neutro se amalgamasen y fusionasen en la lengua hablada evolucionando como uno en prácticamente todas las lenguas romances, salvo en excepciones puntuales como el pronombre «ello» y el artículo «lo», lo que habría favorecido que la terminación de masculino pudiese adquirir también significado de género neutro o no marcado.

Comment: Gracias @walen. He estado buscando un poco en preguntas existentes. A mi me suena que algo como lo que he puesto yo aquí ya se había aportado en otras contribuciones. Pensé en buscar un poco sobre lenguajes donde el masculino no es el género inclusivo, para "demostrar" que no eran meramente cuestiones históricas o socioculturales las que motivaban la predominancia del masculino en el lenguaje, pero me di cuenta que igual me iba un poco por las ramas. Buscaré esas aportaciones y si las encuentros las enlazaré aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Para referirse a un colectivo usamos el género neutro que coincide con el masculino. Lo de incluir el femenino es un fenómeno reciente que va en contra de lo dictaminado por la RAE. Esto es castellano básico.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9nero_gramatical#El_g.C3.A9nero_en_espa.C3.B1ol

Comment: Eh? El neutro en español corresponde en flexión con el masculino para adjetivos, pero no hay sustantivos neutros ni concordancia neutro-plural (sólo neutro-singular)